# Scrape a span text from multiple span elements of same name within a p tag in a website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the text from the span tag within multiple span tags with similar names. Using python, beautifulsoup to parse the website.
Just cannot uniquely identify that specific gross-amount span element. 
The span tag has `name=nv` and a data value but the other one has that too. I just wanna extract the gross numerical dollar figure in millions.
Please advise.

this is the structure :

```
<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
 <span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
 <span name="nv" data-value="93122">93,122</span>
 <span class="ghost">|</span>
 <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
 <span name="nv" data-value="69,645,701">$69.65M</span>
</p>
```

Want the text from second span under span class= text muted Gross.

Comment: Hi, It is very difficult to understand and answer your question in its current form. Can you provide *the url, the expected result, and code that you have tried*?

Comment: Hi,
this is the structure :
<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
                <span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
                <span name="nv" data-value="93122">93,122</span>
                <span class="ghost">|</span>
                <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
                <span name="nv" data-value="69,645,701">$69.65M</span>
        </p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is find the `<span>` tag that has the text 'Gross:'. Then, once it finds that tag, tell it to go find the next `<span>` tag (which is the value amount), and get that text.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


html = '''<p class="sort-num_votes-visible">
 <span class="text-muted">Votes:</span>
 <span name="nv" data-value="93122">93,122</span>
 <span class="ghost">|</span>
 <span class="text-muted">Gross:</span>
 <span name="nv" data-value="69,645,701">$69.65M</span>
</p>'''

soup = BS(html, 'html.parser')

gross_value = soup.find('span', text='Gross:').find_next('span').text
```

**Output:**

```
print (gross_value)
$69.65M
```

or if you want to get the `data-value`, change that last line to:

```
gross_value = soup.find('span', text='Gross:').find_next('span')['data-value']
```

**Output:**

```
print (gross_value)
69,645,701
```

And finally, if you need those values as an integer instead of a string, so you can aggregate in some way later:

```
gross_value = int(soup.find('span', text='Gross:').find_next('span')['data-value'].replace(',', ''))
```

**Output:**

```
print (gross_value)
69645701
```

Comment: Have solved it like this :

gross_value = div.find_next('p', {'class': 'sort-num_votes-visible'})
g1_value = div.find_next('span', {'name': 'nv'})
g2_value = g1_value.find_next_sibling('span', {'name': 'nv'})
    if g2_value:
        #print(g2_value.text)
        gross_list.append(g2_value.text)
    else:
        #print("NAN")
        gross_list.append('NAN')

print(*gross_list, sep='\n')

Here I iterated in side the div to find the next 'span' as the next sibling element which did the trick.
Thank yo all.